# ConTeXt, YAML and Ansible

Tags: context

I was reading the [TUG interview with Pavneet Arora](https://tug.org/interviews/arora.html) who was this year organizer of [TUG meeting in Toronto](https://tug.org/tug2016/) and one thing caught my attention. Mr Arora described use of ConTeXt to develop “specification-driven documentation” with an emphasis on YAML as a main trust of his current professional work. [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) as some people probably know is human-readable data serialization language but more importantly for me personally is the language used to write play books for [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), a widely used configuration, management, and orchestration software.

Unfortunately I was not quite able to understand the connection between ConTeXt and YAML described in the above article so here I plea for help. 
Could anybody kindly describe to me the relationship between ConTeXt and YAML? I have this  vague idea that would be possible to write Ansible play book in ConTeXt which will then be able "TeX" into YAML play book but also into the printable documentation. The idea of course is not original and people will recognize Don Knuth's [WEB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WEB) which can produce both Pascal code and printable TeX document.

Comment: Vagueness is in vogue, perhaps?

Comment: Maybe you could email Pavneet to ask for more details.

Comment: Do you know his e-mail? I tried to contact him through Linkedln but the interface is not usable due to the fake security.

Comment: »... along with scripts to generate the desired output on demand.«  This sounds more like Pavneet had a script to generate ConTeXt source from YAML input rather than ConTeXt itself typesetting YAML.

Comment: Actually, it should be very easy to write your own YAML integration with ConTeXt.  Just google [Lua YAML parser](https://www.google.de/search?q=Lua+YAML+parser).

Comment: He posts regularly on the context mailing list. You can see his email address there or send a message to him on the mailing list to see what he meant exactly

Comment: @Henri Menke Thank you so much for you kind answer. Mr. Arora contacted me via PM. He mentioned your idea which I like a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used [`lyaml`](https://github.com/gvvaughan/lyaml) to produce a useless minimal example (It is more a proof of concept).

I'm on Debian GNU/Linux where I installed the package `lua-yaml`.  I had to symlink the files

```
/usr/share/lua/5.2/lyaml.lua
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/yaml.so
```

to the working directory, because ConTeXt only searchs `/usr/local/...`  for me.

```
\startluacode
local lyaml = require "lyaml"

function parseyaml(buf)
    local input  = buffers.getcontent(buf)
    local struct = lyaml.load(input, { all = true })
    for _,section in pairs(struct) do
       context.startitemize()
       for title,element in pairs(section) do
          context.item(title)
          context.startitemize()
          for _,entry in pairs(element) do
             context.item(entry)
          end
          context.stopitemize()
       end
       context.stopitemize()
    end
end
\stopluacode

\startbuffer[grocery]
---
# A list of tasty fruits
fruits:
    - Apple
    - Orange
    - Strawberry
    - Mango
---
fruits: ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Mango']
...
\stopbuffer

\starttext

\startpacked
  \ctxlua{parseyaml("grocery")}  
\stoppacked

\stoptext
```

[image]