# Why doesn't luatex recognise lyaml, a manually installed library (when lua itself does)?

Tags: luatex, lua

I want to parse a yaml file containing my CV data and then write content programatically, in LaTeX, from that data. I have installed the relevant library `lyaml` and it works, but `lua(la?)tex` doesn't detect it. Why not, and how can I change that?

### Further details

In case these help anyone to diagnose my problem...

The following program works:

```lua
-- requirements
local io    = require "io"
local lyaml = require "lyaml"

-- get yaml data as a string
local yaml_file   = "cv.yaml"
local f           = assert(io.open(yaml_file, 'r'))
local yaml_string = f:read('a')
f:close()

local cv_table = {}

-- convert yaml string to lua table
cv_table.t = lyaml.load(yaml_string)

for key, value in pairs(cv_table.t) do
    print(key)  
end
```

It opens the file, reads its contents as a string, closes the file, parses the string as yaml, and then prints each top-level key of the resulting lua table to stdout.

I'm on Debian. In particular, this works because I've installe `lua-yaml`. `dpkg --listfiles lua-yaml` gives me this:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.1-yaml.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.2-yaml.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.3-yaml.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.3
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/lua-yaml
/usr/share/doc/lua-yaml/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/lua-yaml/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/lua-yaml/copyright
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/lua-yaml
/usr/share/lua
/usr/share/lua/5.1
/usr/share/lua/5.1/lyaml
/usr/share/lua/5.1/lyaml/explicit.lua
/usr/share/lua/5.1/lyaml/functional.lua
/usr/share/lua/5.1/lyaml/implicit.lua
/usr/share/lua/5.1/lyaml.lua
/usr/share/lua/5.2
/usr/share/lua/5.2/lyaml
/usr/share/lua/5.3
/usr/share/lua/5.3/lyaml
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.1-yaml.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.2-yaml.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.3-yaml.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/yaml.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/yaml.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.3/yaml.so
/usr/share/lua/5.2/lyaml/explicit.lua
/usr/share/lua/5.2/lyaml/functional.lua
/usr/share/lua/5.2/lyaml/implicit.lua
/usr/share/lua/5.2/lyaml.lua
/usr/share/lua/5.3/lyaml/explicit.lua
/usr/share/lua/5.3/lyaml/functional.lua
/usr/share/lua/5.3/lyaml/implicit.lua
/usr/share/lua/5.3/lyaml.lua``shell
```

However, this does *not* even compile:

```tex
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document} 

\begin{luacode*}

    -- requirements
    local io    = require "io"
    local lyaml = require "lyaml"

    -- get yaml data as a string
    local yaml_file   = "cv.yaml"
    local f           = assert(io.open(yaml_file, 'r'))
    local yaml_string = f:read('a')
    f:close()

    local cv_table = {}

    -- convert yaml string to lua table
    cv_table.t = lyaml.load(yaml_string)

    for key, value in pairs(cv_table.t) do
        tex.print(key)  
    end

\end{luacode*}

\end{document}
```

The tex file is *just* the lua program, wrapped in the appropriate latex, and with `tex.print` replacing `print`. It is in the same directory.

Trying to compile with `lualatex test.tex` gives the following errors:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)...0/texmf-dist/te
x/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:381: attempt to call a nil value (fie
ld 'cpath specification')
stack traceback:
        ...0/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:381: in field '?'
        ...0/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:403: in function <
...0/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:395>
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [\directlua]:3: in main chunk.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
                                                  
l.28 \end{luacode}
```

The same thing happens if I use `\directlua` or the(unstarred `luacode` environment. Same errors, so that's not the problem. The errors concern the `lyaml` library, and go away as soon as I remove it from the code (to be replaced by errors complaining that I'm referencing a library I don't import). As I understand it, these all use `\directlua` under the hood anyway, so they will all suffer the same problems.

So the problem is with the `lyaml` library. Clearly it's installed just fine, so why can't lua(la?)tex see it?

### Things I have tried

I have read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475600/luatex-and-system-luarocks-mismatch-problem). I'm on debian so the comments weren't directly relevant to me, but I was inspired to try symlinking `/usr/share/lua/5.3/lyaml.lua` to `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-lyaml.lua`. This didn't make any difference. I then tried what the comment suggested and ran `sudo fmtutil-sys --byfmt=lualatex` but that also had no effect.

Following [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324124/context-yaml-and-ansible/324411#324411) I have also tried symlinking the relevant files straight into the working dir, but this didn't help either.

Comment: you have installed it for the stock Lua but texlua is a separate Lua implementation so you would need to chage its LUAINPUTS path or copy the lua package into texlua's input path

Comment: note you don't have to wrap the Lua in tex you can use texlua (rather than luatex) to pass a lua file directly/

Comment: probably setting `LUAINPUTS=:/usr/share/lua//` does what you want making luatex search the /usr/share/lua path if nothing found in the standard path oh there is a compiled component so you will need to set CLUAINPUTS as well I think

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's really helpful thanks! I'm very new to luatex. Is this something I should set in `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf.cnf`? Or somewhere else? I'm using latexmk if that's at all relevant. Or if it would be simpler to link/copy the binary in, how could I find texlua's input path?

Comment: you can set it as an environment variable. If you want to set it in texmf.cnf then yes there you can see the comments on each variable in  `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` but don't edit that file it gets overwritten on updates.

Comment: I haven't answered as I don't want to install the library to test, if you get it working can you self answer, saying what you did. (Or someone else may answer of course)

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Maybe `\usepackage{luapackageloader}`
https://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/luatex/generic/luapackageloader/luapackageloader.pdf
Out of curiosity, why `lyaml` vs other YAML libraries? I use `tinyyaml` but not sure it is the right choice.
I have only gotten pure Lua libraries to work.

Comment: Duplicate of [luatex - Using LuaLaTeX and SQLite3 - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218855/using-lualatex-and-sqlite3/372134#372134) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to get this to work. There were three components I needed:

1. `\usepackage{luacode}`. I already had this.
2. `\usepackage{luapackageloader}` (thanks @likethevegetable for the suggestion) From [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luapackageloader): "This package allows LuaTeX to load packages from the default package.path and package.cpath locations. This could be useful to load external Lua modules, including modules installed via LuaRocks".
3. Specify the paths *in lua*. For me, on debian, this was right, but of course others might need different paths:

```tex
\begin{luacode*}
    local my_path = "/usr/share/lua/5.3"
    local my_cpath ="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.3/"
    package.path  = package.path  .. string.format(";%s/?.lua;%s/?/init.lua", my_path, my_path)
    package.cpath = package.cpath .. string.format(";%s/?.so;%s/?/init.so", my_cpath, my_cpath)
\end{luacode*}
```

Comment: This will be useful for me. I currently only use pure Lua packages with my LuaLaTeX uses because I struggled to figure out how to install a Lua + c package to my MiKTeX folders without the use of luarocks. Just to confirm: your `lyaml` package resides in a separate Lua install, and you just use `luapackageloader` and add to the path your separate Lua install. If you can figure this out without a separate Lua install that would be cool. By the way, I use the library `tinyyaml` for my YAML stuff.

Comment: Specifying package.path within the TeX source code itself is bad practice though.